# how can I replace a line containing variables?

Tags: bash, sed

I have a bash script and I want to use that for replacing some lines with a string and add a date to the end of the line:

```sh
#! /bin/bash

today=`date '+%Y_%m_%d__%H_%M_%S'`;

sed -i '3s/.*/CONFIG_LOCALVERSION=/' ~/Desktop/file1 file2 ...
```

Also, can I do this for a range of files that start with a string like "file"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use variable expansion in bash, the variables must be non-quoted or double-quoted. Single quotes will prevent the expansion. On the other hand, you'd want to avoid expansion of `*` in `3s/.*/` in case you have a directory `3s` containing files starting with `.`.

Fortunately, you can just chain strings together, so you can do

```sh
#!/bin/bash

today=$(date '+%Y_%m_%d__%H_%M_%S');

sed -i '3s/.*/CONFIG_LOCALVERSION='"$today"'/' ~/Desktop/file{1,2,Foo}
```

> and can i do this for a range of file that start with a string like "file" ?

The [glob](/questions/tagged/glob) `~/Desktop/file{1,2,Foo}` will expand to `~/Desktop/file1 ~/Desktop/file2 ~/Desktop/fileFoo`. If instead you want to match all files on your Desktop with a name starting with 'file', use `~/Desktop/file*` instead.

Comment: thx,what if i want find a string in some files and replace with desired string?

Comment: i have g3-* named files in a directory and wanna find "local version" in them and replace with "online version"

Comment: So you want to match a specific pattern instead of blindly modifying the 3rd line of each file?

Comment: Put your search regex in place of the `.*`. If you'd like to do the replacements on all lines, leave off the leading `3`. E.g. `sed -i 's/CONFIG_LOCALVERSION=local version/CONFIG_LOCALVERSION='"$today"'/' ~/Desktop/g3-*`